# Using Spark to get names of all columns that have a value over some threshold

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, emr

**Bakground**

We are unloading data from Redshift into S3 and then loading it into a dataframe like so:

```
df = spark.read.csv(path, schema=schema, sep='|')
```

We are using PySpark and AWS EMR (version 5.4.0) with Spark 2.1.0.

**Problem**

I have a Redshift table that is being read into PySpark as CSV.  The records are in this sort of format:

```
url,category1,category2,category3,category4
http://example.com,0.6,0.0,0.9,0.3
```

*url* is VARCHAR and the *category* values are FLOAT between 0.0 and 1.0.

What I want to do is generate a new DataFrame with a single row per category where the value in the original dataset was above some threshold X.  For example, if the threshold were set to 0.5 then I would want my new dataset to look like this:

```
url,category
http://example.com,category1
http://example.com,category3
```

I'm new to Spark/PySpark so I'm not sure how/if this is possible to do so any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Wanted to add my solution (based on Pushkr's code).  We have a TON of categories to load so to avoid hardcoding every single select I did the following:

```
parsed_df = None
for column in column_list:
    if not parsed_df:
        parsed_df = df.select(df.url, when(df[column]>threshold,column).otherwise('').alias('cat'))
    else:
        parsed_df = parsed_df.union(df.select(df.url, when(df[column]>threshold,column).otherwise('')))
if parsed_df is not None:
    parsed_df = parsed_df.filter(col('cat') != '')
```

where *column_list* is a previously generated list of category column names and *threshold* is the minimum value required to select the category.

Thanks again!

Comment: why not to try databrick redshift package which unload and create dataframe in a single statement ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something That I tried -

```
data = [('http://example.com',0.6,0.0,0.9,0.3),('http://example1.com',0.6,0.0,0.9,0.3)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)\
     .toDF('url','category1','category2','category3','category4')

from pyspark.sql.functions import *



df\
    .select(df.url,when(df.category1>0.5,'category1').otherwise('').alias('category'))\
    .union(\
    df.select(df.url,when(df.category2>0.5,'category2').otherwise('')))\
    .union(\
    df.select(df.url,when(df.category3>0.5,'category3').otherwise('')))\
    .union(\
    df.select(df.url,when(df.category4>0.5,'category4').otherwise('')))\
    .filter(col('category')!= '')\
    .show()
```

output :

```
+-------------------+---------+
|                url| category|
+-------------------+---------+
| http://example.com|category1|
|http://example1.com|category1|
| http://example.com|category3|
|http://example1.com|category3|
+-------------------+---------+
```